# Не получается вытащить переменную за пределы функции

Tags: javascript, mysql, база-данных, node.js, функции

Всем привет.

Долго пытаюсь - ничего не выходит.

Есть функция:

```
function chooseMySQL(query, date, callback) {                                           
    var mysql = require('mysql');
        var con = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "host",
          user: "user",
          password: "pass",
          database: "db"
        });
        con.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          con.query("SELECT * FROM `reestr` WHERE `textahk` LIKE '%"+query+"%' AND `dateahk`='"+date+"'", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(err, result)
            })
        });

}
```

И есть обращение к ней:

```
    zapros = chooseMySQL("запрос","18.07.2017",function(err, result){
    logi = result.length;
    return logi
    }); // и вот после этой функции мне нужно получить значение 'zapros'.
```

Как это сделать? Вроде через `return` возвращаю, а ничего не получается.

Убеждён: тут какая-либо элементарнейшая ошибка или непонимание основ работы `return` функций.

Прошу помощи, потому что идей больше нет.

Если суть проблемы не ясна - переформулирую.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Суть в том, что вы не возвращаете данные, а вызываете функцию, в которую передаете данные. Это коллбэк. И ваш ретурн вы не записываете в переменную. В принципе использовать коллбэки нормальная практика в функциональном программировании, но если вы хотите использовать асинхронный код как синхронный, советую обратить внимание на `async`/`await`. Тогда код будет выглядесь следующим образом.

```
function chooseMySQL(query, date) {                                           
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "host",
      user: "user",
      password: "pass",
      database: "db"
    });
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM `reestr` WHERE `textahk` LIKE '%"+query+"%' AND `dateahk`='"+date+"'", function (err, result, fields) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        } else {
            return resolve(result)
        }
        })
        })
    });
```

}

Эта функция вернет промис, который можно использовать, как обычно, но это вас не даст все равно использовать переменную за пределом вызова функции. Поэтому напишем так

```
    zapros = await chooseMySQL("запрос","18.07.2017");
```

И дальше можете использовать переменную как хотите. Но есть одно условие, вызов функции с ключевым словом `await` должен происходить внутни функции помеченой ключевым словом `async`. Например так

```
(async () => {
    zapros = await chooseMySQL("запрос","18.07.2017");
    console.log(zapros)
})()
```

[Промисы](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

[Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Назар, спасибо! Попробовал сделать так, как Вы посоветовали, однако возникла ошибка: в этой строчке "(async () => {". Полностью код: https://pastebin.com/K7y5pS8D

Comment: @BuTaMuh если я верно посчитал, то вы вставили ифи функцию внутрь своей функции chooseMySQL. Этот блок кода это отдельная функция, где вы вызываете асинхронную функцию. Вставьте его после. И какого рода ошибка то?

Comment: Нет, возможно, я не так вырезал отрывок кода. Стоит, вероятно, пояснить (хоть это и указано в тэгах) - речь идёт о NodeJs, при вводе определенной фразы пользователем, происходит chooseMySQL("запрос","18.07.2017") (где "запрос" - определяется пользователем). Итого, вышло так, условно говоря: if ("/запрос Тест) {zapros = await chooseMySQL("Тест","18.07.2017");} И уже после этого (не внутри) идёт функция chooseMySQL. Ошибка: http://dl.stk-servers.ru/err.jpg